# React router dynamic routes not generating as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router-dom and webpack in my project. 
When user click on a certain link based on the date and id, it will take them to an another page.

My routes:

```
 <Switch>
  <Route path="/" exact render={Home} />
  <Route exact path="/surveys/:date" render={Main} />
  <Route path="/surveys/:date/:id" render={Survey} />
  <Route render={() => <h1>404: page not found</h1>} />
</Switch>
```

I want the path to look like this `surveys/june/123` and it works fine on the first click. But the problem is that, when user loads another survey from the sidebar, instead of url changing to `surveys/june/124` it changes to `surveys/june/123/124` and after that it will change to `surveys/june/123/125` and so on. As in, the first loaded id always stays there in the url.

I have tried:

```
<Link to={`${match.url}/${id}`} />
```

and `path-to-regexp`

```
const setPath = compile(match.path);
const newPath = setPath({
      ...match.params,
      id: id,
});
```

and neither of them work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

because you're getting the matched URL every time.
in your first attempt, you told react to take the matched URL and add an id to it. 
If we assume {match.url} gives us 'surveys/june' and then we parse id to it:
Then we get surveys/june/123
but when clicking the link again from the side bar {match.url} gives us 'surveys/june/123' instead of 'survey/june', which you are parsing to id again which by the end yields the result your getting. 
I hope It's clear for you 
a simple solution is to use link this way :

```
<Link to={`surveys/${date}/${id}`} />
```

Comment: this way the URL changes to `surveys/:date/surveys/:date/id`

Comment: can you share the whole component in which you are using Link please

Answer (score 0):

`match.url` contains the params and the `match.path` doesn't contains the params.

**Do this**

```js
<Link to={`/${match.path}/${match.params.date}/${id}`} />
```

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/match

> path - (string) The path pattern used to match. Useful for building
> nested s
>
> url - (string) The matched portion of the URL. Useful
> for building nested s

Comment: the date won't render in the url, it's just `:date`. `surveys/:date/123`

Comment: ok - use this `<Link to={`/${match.path}/${match.params.date}/${id}`} />` .. i have updated the answer